# Write SQL Query to Exclude Records That Are Dated Prior to a Record with a Specific Flag

Tags: sql

I have a table of project budget revisions that has the following main fields: Project, RevisionId, BookDate, and RevisionType. The RevisionType field can be either 'NT' or 'NA', where 'NT' = Net Change and 'NA' = New Amount. When RevisionType of a budget revision is 'NT', it is a net change to the given project's budget. When RevisonType of a budget revision is 'NA', it is an override to all budget revisons for the given project with a date equal to or prior. I am trying to write a SQL query that provides a result that filters out all budget revision records that are overridden with a 'NA' record.

For example unfiltered, the table contains the following data:

[image: Unfiltered Table]

I need the results of the query to return this:

[image: Filtered Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `not exists` and boolean logic:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    revisiontype = 'NA'
    or not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.project = t.project and t1.bookdate > t.bookdate and t1.revisiontype = 'NA'
    )
```

You could also express this with window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        max(case when revisiontype = 'NA' then bookdate end) over(partition by project) max_na_date
    from mytable t
) t
where revisiontype = 'NA' or bookdate > max_na_date or max_na_date is null
```